# Change active view's link's colors UI-Router

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the hack to get the current view as the active state. Seen here:

```
<div class="navlinks1" ng-class="{active: $state.includes('myanmar')}"}>
    <a ui-sref="myanmar">Myanmar</a>
</div>
```

My css looks like this:

```
.navlinks1{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-bottom:1px solid #e6e6e6;
    font-size:14px;
    margin-left:0px;
}

.navlinks1.active {
    background-color: #bdecff;
    color:#ffffff !important; 
}

.navlinks1 a:active {
    color:#ffffff !important; 
}
```

So that works to change the background. What isn't changing are the link colors. I suspect the a:active is not working.

Does anyone know how to change active link colors with UI-Router such that the links to the current view are a different color?

Thanks.

Comment: should not it be like .navlinks1.active a{ } ?

Comment: That is correct. The author has it right below.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine, I think the issue is your style for the link:

```
.navlinks1 a:active {
    color:#ffffff !important; 
}
```

If you want these link colors to change when $state.includes('myanmar'), your css rule should look like this:

```
.navlinks1.active a {
    color:#ffffff !important;
}
```